# How to get nested value in Xcode configuration files?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-config

I'm trying to get a specific value inside my Xcode configuration file.

[image]

So if I were to print item 0 in the example above, I know part of the code is `print(Bundle.main.infoDictionary["Fonts provided by application"])`.
But then if I add `["Item 0"]` to that, it doesn't work.

How do I get around this? And how do I do it if the `"Fonts provided by application"` key is type `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the wrong key. It's `"UIAppFonts"`, not `"Fonts provided by application"`. The latter is just the display shown in Xcode.
2. The result of `Bundle.main.infoDictionary["UIAppFonts"]` is an array, not another dictionary. So you access each element of the array just like you would any other array.

Example:

```
if let fonts = Bundle.main.infoDictionary["UIAppFonts"] as? [String] {
    // List all of the fonts
    for font in fonts {
        print(font)
    }

    // Get the first font
    let font = fonts[0]
    // or more safely
    if let font = fonts.first {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the Array. But I have the same problem with a Dictionary type key and for that one adding [0] didn't work. How would you access that?

Comment: You access values from a dictionary just like you did here for the "UIAppFonts" key. Please review the [Dictionaries](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113) section of the Swift book for more details.

Comment: I tried, but the response I get is `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`

Comment: Right. You have to cast the result appropriately. Something like: `if let someDict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary["SomeKeyThatGivesADictionary"] as? [String:String] { let someValue = someDict[@"someKey"] }`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm really close with this solution you wrote. But I still get two errors I don't fully understand:
1. `String literals in Swift are not preceded by an '@' sign`
2. `Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[String : Any]`
Do you know how I could solve that?

Comment: That `@` is a typo. Take that out.

Answer (score 0):

Info.Plist is a dictionary. So, for accessing the font array you can use

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary["Fonts provided by application"]
```

But for accessing the each element you need to use

```
(Bundle.main.infoDictionary["Fonts provided by application"] as? Array)?.startIndex
```